# Why printing a list gives None?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Printing 'val' gives none. Why this happens in python?

```
nums=[1,2,3,4,5]
k=3
lst = []
for i in range (1, k+1):
    lst.append(nums[-1])
    nums.pop(-1)
val = lst.extend(nums)
print("lst= ", val)
```

Comment: Because `lst.extend` modifies the list in place and returns `None`.  Just remove the `val =` and print("lst= ", lst)`.

Answer (score 2):

The extend function itself returns nothing (`None`). `lst` itself will change as a product of the extend function. Reading the documentation and looking over examples on how to use the function is simple and will go a long way.

```py
lst.extend(nums)
print("lst= ", lst)
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not printing a list, you're printing the return value of `lst.extend(nums)`, which is `None` because `extend` modifies the list rather than retuning a new one.